# Problems finding modules after installing SimpleCV 1.3

Tags: installation, windows-10, importerror, simplecv

I have recently installed SimpleCV on Windows 10 from the superpack.  Everything went well during the installation, and I was able to successfully run the first example problem in "Practical Computer Vision with SimpleCV" (good book, btw) from within IDLE.  Here's the code:

```
from SimpleCV import Camera, Display, Image
cam = Camera()
display = Display()
img = cam.getImage()
img.save(display)
```

Simple enough, and it worked fine.  Where I ran into problems was when I tried to start up the SimpleCV console.  First of all, no link was created on the Windows desktop, and there was nothing for SimpleCV on the Start menu.  So, I tried the other methods listed in the book.  First, from the console, I tried to run it as a Python module:

```
C:\User> python -m SimpleCV.init
```

And what I got back was:

```
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\__init__.py", line 18 in <module>
    from SimpleCV.Shell import *
  File "C:\Python27\;ib\site-packages\SimpleCV\Shell\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Shell import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\Shell\Shell.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise(e)
ImportError:  No module named IPython
```

Next, I tried the listed alternative: just starting python and importing and executing the Shell. Entering:

```
>>> from SimpleCV import Shell
```

resulted in the same error as above.

I also tried installing ipython by running pip.  But, it looks like pip didn't get installed either.

So, what environmental variable did the installation program not set correctly?  Just so you know, I posted this same question on the SimpleCV site, but have not received a response as of yet.

--- 23 Dec 2015
Chipping away at this.  Read the banner on setuputils install.  Ran Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe. Can now call pip.  However, entering this at the command line:

```
C:\Users> pip install ipython
```

gives this error:

```
 C:\Python27\lib\site--packages\pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90:  InsecurePlatformWarning:  A true SSLContext object is not available.  This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cuase certain SSL connections to fail.  For more information, see...
```

So, I'm making progress.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install ipython from source code?

```
$ tar -xzf ipython.tar.gz
$ cd ipython
$ python setup.py install
```

See https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/install/install.html

There are a lot of requirements more. I recommend the SimpleCV's github repository instructions https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV#windows-8